# Magento 2 - Module Block Causes 404 Error

Tags: magento2, module

I have cobbled together a module for Magento 2 that is eventually going to insert a block in to the product page that pulls in other products with a similar attribute (in this case, "range").

When the module is enabled, I see it in the setup_modules table in the database, and see the CSS I've inserted in to the page from the module, however product pages return a 404 error.

If I remove the block call from the catalog_product_view.xml file that references the template, the page loads.

app/code/Company/RangeCollection/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_RangeCollection" setup_version="2.0.1" schema_version="0.0.1" active="true" />
</config>
```

app/code/Company/RangeCollection/Block/RangeCollection.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\RangeCollection\Block;

class RangeCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct {

    protected $_collection;
    protected $_config;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Collection $collection,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_config = $scopeConfig->getValue('range_collection/settings');
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProducts($currentRegion) {
        $limit = $this->getProductLimit();
        $collection = $this->_collection;
            //->addAttributeToFilter('region', 1);
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->order('rand()')
            ->limit($limit);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return $this->_config;
    }

    public function getProductLimit() {
        return $this->_config["limit"];
    }

}
```

app/code/Company/RangeCollection/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\RangeCollection\Block\RangeCollection" name="range.collection" as="range" after="-" template="Company_RangeCollection::list.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Company/RangeCollection/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Core/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <range_collection>
            <settings>
                <limit>4</limit>
            </settings>
        </range_collection>
    </default>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/RangeCollection/view/frontend/templates/list.phtml

```
<?php
$_products = $this->getProducts();
$_config = $this->getConfig();
$_columnWidth = 100 / $this->getProductLimit();
?>

<h2><?php echo __('Other products in this range') ?></h2>

<ul class="products list items featured">
    <?php foreach ($_products as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item" style="width: <?php echo $_columnWidth; ?>%">
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product">
                    <span class="product-item-name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?></span>
                </a>
                <?php echo $this->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you defined registration.php file in module root

Comment: I have, yes:


<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_RangeCollection',
    __DIR__
);

_Excuse the rubbish formatting!_

Comment: Have to defined routes.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define di.xml file at **app/code/Company/RangeCollection/etc/di.xml**

add below code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct" type="Company\RangeCollection\Block\RangeCollection" /> 

</config>
```

Edit:

Change below line in file **app/code/Company/RangeCollection/Block/RangeCollection.php** :

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Collection $collection,
```

to:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
```

Comment: Added this but still not working. I've just tried bin/magento setup:di:compile and now I'm getting: Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Collection does not exist

Comment: Updated answer check it

Comment: It was my own mistake, I'd written Resource as opposed to ResourceModel. Compiled and now I'm seeing the block output on the page.